# Connecting a Sharepoint Custom list with an external Data-source 

Tags: wss-3.0

I am planning to connect a Sharepoint Custom list with an external Data-source.

External DB will be in Access 2007 format.

More Information:
I need a solution that we can connect our sharepoint list (one-way) to online db in a way that new  information is directly updated in the sharepoint list, whilst other info changed in sharepoint list  is not synced back to original value.

Is there a way to solve this?

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Data Source connections available for DataViewWebParts in SharePoint Designer 2007?

Comment: I use Wss 3.0, will it work in it?

Comment: It should do, yes. WSS doesn't have Business Data Catalogue features, but in SharePoint Designer, I believe you can create a DataViewWebPart which opens up a data connection to another database, including Access.